# How to publish a dapp from Superblocks?

Tags: blockchain, decentralized-applications

I build a simple dapp using https://iot-academy.superblocks.com/ , how can I publish it online on a normal server?

Answer (score 0):

You can host these DAPP in the  GitHub pages or in CDN. If not you can also download it from the superblock and host it locally using MyEtherWallet.

Apart from that even you can pay a rental and host in the Ethereum network.